# TLS / SSL implementation for Desktop applications developed using Delphi

Tags: delphi, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, indy

I have a desktop client/server application. Both client and server are developed using Delphi 10.2. Application server has been deployed as a Windows service.

My requirement is to implement TLS/SSL to secure the communication between client and server. For this I have used Indy with `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` on the server side and `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` on the client side.
For testing purposes, I have used self-signed certificates.

During testing of this setup , I had to setup OpenSSL on each client workstation. Also, I copied `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` to the `system32` folder.

So part of the problem is:

1. Could this configuration of client workstations be avoided? My understanding with TLS/SSL is that it is server which needs to be configured to enable TLS/SSL.
2. Since my testing is based on self signed-certificates, I did not install any certificate on client machine. What is the role of certificates for the client machine?

Comment: 1. Your understanding is incorrect. Both peers have to speak TLS/SSL. Both peers therefore need the software. 2. The client has to trust the server, meaning it needs the certificate of a signer of the server's certificate, in this case itself.

Comment: So the conclusion is that client must be configured to use TLS / SSL ? this can not be avoided

Comment: @Deepakkumarjain no, it cannot be avoided, in this situation. Also, do not put the DLLs in the system32 folder, they don't belong there. Put them in your app's folder  instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thanks for pointing me in right direction.